# Webscraping with python - with interactive website

Tags: python, web-scraping

Can anybody recommend a python package to extract data from the Dutch met office website:

https://www.knmi.nl/nederland-nu/weer/waarschuwingen-en-verwachtingen/weer-en-klimaatpluim

The site shows graphs with forecasts of temperature, rainfall, etc. You can click on the graph and select that the underlying data is shown in a table.

Which python package can I use to go to the site, extract the table data for different forecasts in a dataframe.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use **BeautifulSoup**

Answer (score 0):

Do not listen to the others, the data on this particular page is loaded dynamically with JavaScript therefore BeautifulSoup will not be able to scrape.

**Tip**
Only scrape with BeautifulSoup if you have to, your first port of call should be to expose the api endpoint.

---

You can send a request to the api endpoint and return json containing  the page data.

If you are using a chromium browser press `CTRL + SHIFT + I` & select the network tab. Click `Clear` then click `Record`.
When you refresh the page you will notice the table below will fill up with requests.

[image]

Search the `Name` column for the JSON requests and use the request url and the code below to return JSON

```
import requests
import json

target_url = "https://cdn.knmi.nl/knmi/json/page/weer/waarschuwingen_verwachtingen/ensemble/iPluim/260_99999.json"

r = requests.get(target_url)
weather_data = json.loads(r.text)

print(weather_data['series'])
```

If you can work out the the api parameters you could construct your own requests

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can be useful for dynamic sites https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: Selenium should be the last resort