# Webscraping interactive website without Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to download the list of bin dates from the local council website, https://www.gateshead.gov.uk/article/3150/Bin-collection-day-checker, I have a solution using Selenium but I would like to perform the scraping without Selenium/chromedriver.

Following the advice here [Webscraping with python - with interactive website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73916666/webscraping-with-python-with-interactive-website)
I have loaded up devtools in Chrome to watch what is going on, it looks like it gets a session ID then, using the supplied address data, does the look up. I tried looking for the details to work out how I would do this as an API request rather than scraping the page but I'm not having any luck/don't have the technical know how on modern web design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I can help with this. So you have gotten to the table that says what day each bin type is collected. If that's the case this should extract the table for you and print the results.

```
table = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')

for row in table:
    data = []
    table_rows = table.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
    for rows in table_rows:
            columns = rows.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td') #this is just taking the data from each row
            for column in columns:
                column_data = column.text
            data.append(column_data)
print(data)
```

This should get the data you need I'm currently in work but will be happy to take a look further when I get home. In the example above we look for the tag of the table, next it gets each row 'tr', after we have the rows we get the data 'td'. we can then convert it to text and save it. Then for checking we print the data.

You could also run it on Github and just extract the scraped data from there or use a workflow to automatically do that and send you the results. I'm not sure how else you could do it without using a service or an import

I Hope this helps please let me know if you need anything else. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Morddekaiser, Ive got the  Selenium version working but I'm looking to replicate pulling the data without using Selenium - I'm trying to run it on a device that runs python but can't run up any of the browser drivers.

Comment: you could run it on Github and just extract the scraped data from there or use a workflow to automatically do that and send you the results. I'm not sure how else you could do it without using a service or an import.

Comment: I hadn't considered that but I've now got it up and running on GitHub, thanks!Iif you want to add that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Hey im glad to hear that :) yes I've updated the answer to include it if you wouldn't mind accepting the answer for me that would be great! have a great day!